# i want to make phone call from flutter app, and the number comes from firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

i get the mobile number from user which will be stored in FireStore and i want to make a button and on the OnPressed i want to take the number to the mobile dial to make a call, can anybody suggest any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you can get the phone number from your FireStore by yourself, as a String.

The easiest way to achieve it afterwards on both iOS and Android is to use the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package.

By adding this in your pubspec.yaml :

```
  url_launcher: ^5.5.0
```

From there, you just have to build a string beginning with the tel:// protocol indicator and the phone number to call.

I would do this as its own widget for proper separation and ease of use in other apps or somewhere else in your app :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class CallNumberButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String phoneNumber;

  CallNumberButton({@required this.phoneNumber});

  void _callNumber() async {
    String url = "tel://" + this.phoneNumber;
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
    } else {
    throw 'Could not call $phoneNumber';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () => _callNumber(),
      child: Text(
        'Call',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#-readme-tab-).

First install it:

```
dependencies:
  url_launcher: ^5.5.0
```

And then use it like:

```
      MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          launch('tel://1234567890');
        },
        child: Text(
          'Call',
        ),
      ),
```